# Prove set $S = \{(x,y): x \in [a,b], 0 \leq y \leq f(x) \}$ is Jordan measurable

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be Riemann integrable. Suppose that $f(x) \geq 0$ on $[a,b]$. Let set $S = \{(x,y): x \in [a,b], 0 \leq y \leq f(x) \}$. Show that set S is Jordan Measurable with area $\int_a^b f(x) dx$.

First we show that the graph of $f$ in $\Bbb R^2$ is zero content. Denote $Gr(f) = \{(x,f(x)): x \in [a,b]\}$. Given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists partition $P$ of interval $[a,b]$ such that $S_Pf - s_pf < \epsilon$ where $$S_P f = \sum_{n=1}^N \sup\{f(x): x \in [x_{n-1}, x_n]\}(x_n-x_{n-1}) \text{ and } s_Pf = \sum_{n=1}^N \inf\{f(x): x \in [x_{n-1}, x_n]\}(x_n - x_{n-1})$$
Let rectangle $R_n = [x_{n-1}, x_n]\times[m_n, M_n]$. Then $Gr(f) \subset \cup_{n=1}^N R_n$. So $$area(\cup_{n=1}^N R_n) = \sum_{n=1}^N (M_n- m_n)(x_n - x_{n-1}) = S_Pf - s_Pf < \epsilon$$
and $Gr(f)$ is a set of zero content.

The difficulty is showing that set $S$ is Jordan Measurable, that is, it is bounded and has boundary of zero content. At each discontinuity of $f$ (and at endpoints $a$, $b$), set $S$ contains a vertical line segment. $\partial S$ is the union of line segments and $Gr(f)$.

One idea is to create finitely many rectangles covering all vertical line segments in S caused by a discontinuity in $f$. However, the set of discontinuities of $f$ in $\Bbb R$ may not be of zero content; for example, Thomae's function is integrable yet discontinuous on $\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]$.

How do we solve this problem? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This is part of the conclusion of Fubini's theorem (if I remember correctly)